# How to edit a function in your code in swift?

Tags: swift, game-development

I'm fairly new to coding and trying to make a game where you attack an enemy with a shop/potions. I sell a potion for 50% more damage and i don't know how to edit the attack function while the code is ran. this is what i have

this is in class Character

```
func attack(enemy: Character, extra: Bool)
    {
        if extra == false
        {let dmgDealt = Int.random(in:0...30)
        updateHealth(amount: -dmgDealt, target: enemy)}
        else if extra == true
        {
        let dmgDealt = Int.random(in:15...45)
        updateHealth(amount: -dmgDealt, target: enemy)
        }
        
    }
```

and

```
func shop(target: Character, currency: myCoins)
    {
        print("Hello! Welcome to the shop! Our stock includes: \nHarming Potion: You do 50% more damage. 200 Coins.\nHealth Potion: Gives a one-time       grant of 75 health. 150 Coins.\nTurtle Potion: You heal for more health but are more susceptible to attacks from the enemy. 300 coins.\n Damage Potion: Throw this at the enemy to deal 50 Damage! 200 coins.")
        let potionChoice = String(readLine()!)
        print("Good Choice!")
        switch potionChoice
        {
            case "harming":
            currency -= 200

            case "health":
            currency -= 150
            case "turtle":
            currency -= 300
            case "damage":
            currency -= 200
        }
     }
```

i haven't done the others yet but i cant figure out how to do it

i tried making a bool where if it is true then deal extra damage but idk how that works

Comment: The shop func has to change something to be used later. How can you model the state of potions possessed by the player?

Comment: else if extra == true
        {
        let dmgDealt = 50
        updateHealth(amount: -dmgDealt, target: enemy)
        }